# Python and JavaScript/AngularJS documentation on the one server?

Tags: python, angularjs, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, docstring

The advantages of this approach include:

- Consistent [docstring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring) syntax everywhere
- Centralsied documentation server; find all your docs in one place
- Search and jump-to-source from any documented function or class; in either language

Are there any modules integrating with [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) or similar; which generate+put your JavaScript and Python documentation in one place?

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?q=sphinx+autodoc+javascript

Comment: I've been using sphinx-jsapidoc (since before I asked this question); and wasn't too impressed. I got it working, but it doesn't handle semantics (such as directives and modules); and additionally the jump-to-implementation feature seems broken.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your question is about public documentation or in-house documentation of some of your projects.

For the former you want to see this: http://devdocs.io/

Also [devdocs document scrapers are open source](https://github.com/Thibaut/devdocs), so you should be able to use them for your own projects to build custom devdocs.io.